# OpenGL: Why glTextureSubImage2D crashes?

Tags: opengl, texture

I'm trying to create single-channel (no mipmaps) texture initialized with my custom pixel data, but it crashes on glTextureSubImage2D. Any idea why?

```
const std::vector<GLubyte> myData(1025 * 1025, 0);
GLuint texture;
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &texture);
glTextureStorage2D(texture, 1, GL_R8, 1025, 1025);
glTextureSubImage2D(texture, 0, 0, 0, 1025, 1025, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &myData[0]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Pixel transfer operations are governed by more than just your parameters to a pixel transfer function. They are also governed by [parameters passed to the `glPixelStore` functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_parameters).

Of particular interest to you is `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`. This tells OpenGL what the byte alignment for each row of data is in your array. By default, this value is *four*, not one.

This means that OpenGL will believe that the second row of your image starts at this address: `&myData[1028]`, since 1025 is not aligned to 4 bytes. And that means it will run off the end of your allocated buffer eventually.

If you are using data with 1-byte alignment for rows, you must inform OpenGL of this by calling `glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`. Note that [you should not do this by default; do it only when dealing with byte aligned data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11045278/734069).